# Finding block structure of a tensor

Tags: algorithms, tensor-decomposition

Are there any well-known algorithms for partitioning a dense tensor into block-sparse form?

In other words, I need to find a set of non-overlapping blocks that contain all non-zero entries of the tensor, while trying to minimize both the number of blocks and the the number of zeroes in each block.

The tensor in question is 3D if that helps.

Comment: That seems like a typical NP problem :-)

Comment: I don't need an exact solution, a decent heuristic will do.  This is about optimizing a computation in SIMD environment.

Comment: Are you allowed to reorder rows and columns to form blocks, or are you only seeking to identify blocks that are already there?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Is this a use case for Metis or Parmetis?

Comment: @causative Yes, I can reorder freely in one of the dimensions, and I can reorder columns in the other two.  Though I believe my data is already well-clustered, and all I need now if to identify sub-blocks.

Comment: Try googling "clustering high dimensional data". Though this doesn't explicitly take advantage of your 3D "grid", the idea remains the same.